# How do I get a div to grow horizontally off the screen

Tags: css, html

I have a layout that has a table in it. I would like the div containing the table to grow horizontally if the data the table contains is wide enough to go off the screen. It currently works when the data goes off the screen vertically but not horizontally. This is the code:

```css
#main-content {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#field-selection-area {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 1px #AAAAAA solid;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
#field-selection-area ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0;
}
#field-table-area {
  border-right: 1px #AAAAAA solid;
  border-bottom: 1px #AAAAAA solid;
}
.field-area {
  border-top: 1px #AAAAAA solid;
  padding: 4px;
}
#table-area {
  border-top: 1px #AAAAAA solid;
}
#table-area table td {
  border: 1px #AAAAAA solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <div id="field-selection-area">
    <ul class="no-text-selection">
      <li>Period</li>
      <li>Market</li>
      <li>Trade ID</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="field-table-area">
    <div id="field-config-area">
      <div id="filter-field-area" class="no-text-selection field-area">
        Drop Filter Fields Here
      </div>

      <div id="row-field-area" class="no-text-selection field-area">
        Drop Row Fields Here
      </div>

      <div id="column-field-area" class="no-text-selection field-area">
        Drop Column Fields Here
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="table-area">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
          <td>18.0</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is it working when the screen is wide enough:

[image: Working when screen is wide enough]
But if I resize the screen and then scroll this is what happens:

[image: Not working when screen size too small]
In the image above I have scrolled to the right slightly. I would like the table to be fully contained. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use overflow: auto on your table-area:

```
#table-area{
    border-top: 1px #AAAAAA solid;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**demo:**

```css
#main-content{
    display: flex;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#field-selection-area{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    border: 1px #AAAAAA solid;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

#field-selection-area ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
}

#field-table-area{
    border-right: 1px #AAAAAA solid;
    border-bottom: 1px #AAAAAA solid;
}

.field-area {
    border-top: 1px #AAAAAA solid;
    padding: 4px;
}

#table-area{
    border-top: 1px #AAAAAA solid;
    overflow:auto;
}

#table-area table td{
    border: 1px #AAAAAA solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pivot Web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-content">
    <div id="field-selection-area">
        <ul class="no-text-selection">
            <li>Period</li>
            <li>Market</li>
            <li>Trade ID</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="field-table-area">
        <div id="field-config-area">
            <div id="filter-field-area" class="no-text-selection field-area">
                Drop Filter Fields Here
            </div>

            <div id="row-field-area" class="no-text-selection field-area">
                Drop Row Fields Here
            </div>

            <div id="column-field-area" class="no-text-selection field-area">
                Drop Column Fields Here
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="table-area">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                    <td>18.0</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That does work although not in the way I was expecting. Would you say it is better to have the scroll on the table rather than the whole screen?

Comment: @Boomah: I'd say this would be the better option since it means you're not leaving a stupid amount of blank space in your markup.